# How can I look for a keyword in a string in python?

Tags: python

I have a Python program where I need to find a keyword that the user types in, like the word "schedule" in a string that may contain other unknown words as well. So far I have this but it is always saying that `favorite` is `True.`

```
option = input("Would you like to start your schedule or open a favorite site? ")
schedule = False
favorite = False

if "schedule" in option:
    schedule = True
elif "favorite" or "site" in option:
    favorite = True
else:
    print("Please pick an option")

print(schedule)
print(favorite)
```

Comment: `"favorite" or "site" in option` doesn't do what you expect. It should be `"favorite" in option or "site" in option` instead.

Comment: This code seems reasonable enough.  Are you actually typing "schedule<enter>" at the prompt?  Due to the bug Mattheus mentions you will never hit `else:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common mistake people do.

```
import webbrowser

webpage = "https://classroom.google.com/u/1/h"
option = input("Would you like to start your schedule or open a favorite site? ")
schedule = False
favorite = False

if "schedule" in option:
    schedule = True
elif "favorite" in option or "site" in option:
    favorite = True
else:
    print("Please pick an option")

print(schedule)
print(favorite)
```

You messed up on the second if statement.
You did this

```
elif "favorite" or "site" in option:
```

Instead do this

```
elif "favorite" in option or "site" in option:
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved the issue!

Comment: @ZacharyF you can mark this answer as the solution to your question to help others in the future :)